# Why does it work to return an int in a method which should return an object?

Tags: c++

Why does it work to return an `int` in the method `B minus` if the method is supposed to return an object of type `B`?

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    int a;
public:
    B(int i=0)
    {
        a=i;
    }
    B minus()
    {
        return (1-a);
    }
};

int main()
{
    B x(18);
    x = x.minus();
    std::cout << x.a << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't mark your constructor `explicit`.

Comment: Look at your `B` constructor.  How are `B`'s constructed?

Comment: I assume since the constructor takes int, it implicitly constructs from int, as well.

Comment: [Read this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-93/) to see how the `explicit` keyword works.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A constructor with a single argument is considered a *converting constructor*.  When an argument of type X is needed, and a type Y is given instead, the compiler will look for a converting constructor (or a type conversion operator) from Y to X.  In this case it finds one, using your `B(int)` constructor.  In essence, your `return (1-a);` is changed to `return B(1-a);`.

As mentioned in several other (also correct) answers, if you do not wish the constructor to be considered a converting constructor, you should preface it with the `explicit` keyword.

Answer (score 27):

The line

```
return (1-a);
```

calls the implicit conversion constructor

```
B(int i=0)
{
    a=i;
}
```

So it's the same as writing

```
return B(1-a);
```

<sub>Note that the copy constructor is still generated, unless you `delete` it.</sub>

---

If you want to avoid that, write

```
   explicit B(int i=0)
// ^^^^^^^^
   {
       a=i;
   }
```

this will actually force a user to write

```
return B(1-a);
```

Answer (score 13):

This is happening because single-argument constructor can be used as an implicit cast from argument type to object type.

In your case, you have a constructor which accepts an argument of type `int`, so this constructor can be used to convert `int` into `B`.

To prevent those constructors to be used in conversion, you should mark constructor `explicit` - and it's a good practice to do so for all single-argument constructors, since in practice those implicit conversions are more often undesired than desired.